# Is it possible to animate the Twenty Eleven menu?

Tags: menus, jquery, theme-twenty-eleven

I have a menu in my Twenty Eleven child theme that has some hierarchical items.  Twenty Eleven handles it just fine, of course, but my client likes the fancy-looking menu animation that you can see on [this site](http://taf.org/).  I don't need the horizontal style that shows up under the "Resources by Topic" item, just the on-hover expansion like the "Who We Are" heading.  I have used jQuery quite a bit before in other (non-WordPress) websites, but don't know where to begin in this case.  Is this animation possible with Twenty Eleven?

Comment: Gosh I love downvotes without comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. It is possible with some jquery. I think your question is still too broad. Also, asking for plugin recommendation is on the don't ask list. Id start doing some Google searches for implementing jquery in a wordpress menu, attempt and maybe ask for help with your code if it is not working. Otherwise a quick search for wordpress menu plugins will give you lots of addon choices.

Comment: Thank you.  I have done so and found a suitable replacement.